# java.lang.NullPointerException: Project directory not specified

Tags: gradle, android-studio

When building a project in Android Studio (build AI-130.729444), I keep getting this exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Project directory not specified:
>   Project directory not specified

It starts happening out of nowhere, and editing the gradle files does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the build settings (the little wrench in the Messages view) and uncheck "Use external build".

Comment: Maybe. I have moved to Eclipse since.

Answer (score 7):

You may have only a partially checked-in project.  In particular, if you have no .idea/gradle.xml file, this error will occur.

Comment: I found my error project's .idea/gradle.xml was so few, so I check my another project, they got several setting in it. So I copy and move to the empty, then it just works.

Comment: The file doesn't seem to contain anything workspace specific, should it be in your source control repo?

Comment: @AustynMahoney I think that it's not necessary because if you import your project with AndroidStudio using Gradle - Studio will configure everything in .idea folder

Comment: What is gradle.xml?  How does it get generated??

Answer (score 7):

Building off of Duane's answer and Edward's suggestion, add this `.idea/gradle.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="GradleSettings">
    <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
      <GradleProjectSettings>
        <option name="distributionType" value="WRAPPED" />
        <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        <option name="useAutoImport" value="true" />
      </GradleProjectSettings>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

... which is the contents of the file from a new, empty Android Studio project.

Comment: I found that entering the full path for externalProjectPath worked

Comment: Why would you do that though? Then your project file will be localized to your current dev box, and won't work with other boxes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be DEFAULT_WRAPPED??

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after updating android studio, I just cleaned my build and rebuilt the project and it was fixed, hope it  helps someone