# Android Studio compiling legacy project (not gradle) NullPointerException project directory not specified

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to build in android studio, I'm using external build and not gradle.

I keep getting java.lang.NullPointerException: Project directory not specified: Project directory not specified when I try to build.

I have the android SDK set up for the projects, so I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563461/java-lang-nullpointerexception-project-directory-not-specified

Comment: @AmitPrajapati This person uses gradle

Comment: i think you need to export project as gradle from ecllipse

Comment: @AmitPrajapati Please could you be more specific, as this project as never used gradle to build

Comment: if your project have not gradle or maven build it will not work on android studio.

Comment: @AmitPrajapati That is not correct, I have built many projects without Gradle or Maven.

Comment: in android studio or ecllipse

Comment: @AmitPrajapati in AndroidStudio